# Create a web button that changes when hovering and then again after being clicked

Tags: html, css

I would like to create a roll-over image that after having been clicked changes to another image. For example, when the button hasn't been clicked, it shows image 1:

When hovering above it, it would change to image 2:

Then, after the user has clicked the button, it would change to image 3 and stay like that till the page was refreshed:

In addition, when a user presses the button, it would open the link in a new tab.

This is what I have so far:
`<img src="image/b1n.png" alt="Button 1" id="Image2" height="53" width="281">`

Comment: Are you using a stylesheet? If you are create a class and apply a hover attribute to it. Then another class for the current page.

Comment: What do you have so far? I don't see anything.

Comment: Use jQuery `onClick` and `hover` functions.

Comment: Where is your code attempt? `<img src="image/b1n.png" alt="Button 1" id="Image2" height="53" width="281">` does not count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS for the hover:

```
.button {
    background: #2c82b9;
}
.button:hover {
    background: #359cdd;
}
.button.clicked, .button.clicked:hover {
    background: #aa0000;
}
```

Then, use JavaScript for the click:

```
<div class="button" alt="Button 1" id="Image2" onClick="this.className = this.className + ' clicked';"></div>
```

[**See this demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/bLJpL/)

**The `:active` pseudo-class should not be used** because its implementation varies in different browsers.

Comment: How would I using this, link it to a website link that will open in a new tab? Thanks so far, :D

Comment: If you use `<a href="URL" class="button" target="_blank" onClick="this.className = this.className + ' clicked';">Open Page</a>`, then it should work.

Comment: This is what I get. http://jsfiddle.net/GB3Gt/ I'd like the button to be it, not a short text in the corner.

Comment: That's because you left the `div` tag in there. When you just have the hyperlink by itself, it looks [**like this.**](http://jsfiddle.net/GB3Gt/3/)

Comment: But as said above, I would like it too be an image, like here: ouabmc.net/apply/steps.html, so without text and the size of the image.

Comment: Still haven't figured this out, and help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Add a class to the button then do the following:
For the normal state.

```
button.class{
    background-image: url("images/image.jpg");
}
```

For hover:

```
button.class:hover{
    background-image: url("images/image2.jpg");
}
```

For active:

```
button.class:active{
    background-image: url("images/image3.jpg");
}
```

Note that active pseudo class is not friendly with some IE versions.

Answer (score 0):

Add a style sheet to your page. In it have something like:

```
.roll-over { background-image:url('image.png'); }
.roll-over:hover { background-image:url('image2.png'); }
.current { background-image:url('image3.png'); }
```

Apply the current to the current page link, and the roll over to the other links.
May need some work but thats the general idea

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS to create the hover affect

```
 **CSS**
 #Image1:hover { background-image: url("dir/image2.jpg"); }
```

Then use simple JavaScript code to handle the click event to change to image 3

```
  **HTML**
 <img src="image/b1n.png" alt="Button 1" id="Image1" height="53" width="281" onclick="changeImage()">

 **JavaScript**
 function changeImage() {
      document.getElementById("Image1").src = "dir/image3.jpg";
 }
```